# why does my npm install download a massive amount of packages in my node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I don't have much, but npm install gives me so many other packages I don't need

```
"dependencies": {
"require-dir": "^0.3.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
"gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
"gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0"
},
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"repository": {
"type": "git",
"url": ""
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: The packages you use depend on them. Either directly, or because they depend on packages (that depend on packages)* that depend on them.

Comment: [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) for instance depends on gulplog, has-gulplog, lodash, make-error-cause, through2, uglify-js, and vinyl-sourcemaps-apply; most of those have more dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

When you use npm to install your gulp dependencies, you also install the dependencies of your dependencies. Dependency graphs are complex, even if you think you only use a few packages *explicitly*, those packages could be standing on the shoulders of a vast amount of libraries.

Follow-up:
[Guide to NPM](http://nodesource.com/blog/an-absolute-beginners-guide-to-using-npm/)